# c# serial port flushing for small data chunks

Tags: c#, serial-port, flush

I'm writing a small byte array of two bytes using something like the following:

```
int bytes_to_write = 2;
port.Write(byte_buffer, buffer_offset, bytes_to_write);
```

It appears as though the underlying libraries are waiting for more data to come through before writing it to the port. Is this the correct behaviour and can I force it to write the small chunk immediately? Some of the forums say using:

```
port.BaseStream.Flush();
```

will cause the correct behaviour but others say this doesn't work. I've run a couple of tests and it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Cheers, 
Richard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you *sure* the data isn't getting written to the port? I've dealt with the `SerialPort` module extensively and have written single bytes out just fine. There should be no need to call `Flush()`.

Set a breakpoint with the debugger after the `port.Write` call and inspect the `port` object. Is the `BytesToWrite` property `> 0`?

**Edit**: Also, make sure your `buffer_offset` argument is `0`.

Comment: I'm using PortMon to watch it and it is getting written out but with the next lot of data - are there any settings that would make it wait?

Comment: Are you talking about adding a delay before `Write()`? You could use `Thread.Sleep` for that

Comment: I'm reading from a data stream and writing it to the serial port as it comes. The hardware on the port is expecting the 2 bytes and timing out. I was looking with port mon as to what happened and it seems there are appearing with the next lot of data.

Comment: Can you elaborate. Are the two bytes getting written, but the hardware shows the data in chunks of four bytes or more? You may have to change the baud rate, or add a `Thread.Sleep()` delay before each `Write()`.

Answer (score 9):

This will get written to the serial port driver transmit buffer without any extra help.  Flush is not required.  If it doesn't make it to the device then you've probably got a handshake problem.  A classic mistake is to leave it set to None and not setting the DtrEnable and RtsEnable properties to true.

It can also be a wiring problem, shake that out by using another program like HyperTerminal or Putty.  Last but not least: it is difficult to keep a device happy that uses timeouts when you're debugging your code.

Answer (score 3):

I have a very similar situation. I try to write on a serial port from c# to an Arduino board. 
I can write into the serial port but data are finally send only after close and open the port. I try several settings, may be that should help you. DtrEnable is certainly the most important one.

```
port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
port.Open();
port.DiscardInBuffer();
port.DiscardOutBuffer();
port.DtrEnable = true;
```

Comment: You help me. Thanks